# Issue with foreach and loop statement in php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach

I have a number of `$competitors` (which is an array of objects retrieved from MySQL) (say 9) for which I have `$competitors[i]->minSingleCarefee` data, i.e. fee data. I want to make an average of this fee data, but It may be that the dataset is not complete, i.e. I do not have fee data for all of the 9 competitors. I therefore keep track of that by using an if statement and incrementing `$data_available` if the fee data is available.

My problem is that it seems that the code is flawed as it only returns the fee value for the first competitor... and I have no idea why! Also $data_available always end up being 0 when I echo it.

```
//declaring variables
$mm_avg_fees = 0;
$data_available = 0;

//function to calculate average fees
function avg_fees($competitors, $mm_avg_fees, $data_available){

        foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {
            //impose condition to increment data_available
            //only if there is data in the minSingleCareFee column for the $competitor
            if ($competitor->minSingleCareFee != NULL) {
                $mm_avg_fees = $mm_avg_fees + $competitor->minSingleCareFee;
                $data_available = $data_available + 1; 
            } else {}
        }
    return $mm_avg_fees / $data_available;
}

echo echo 'The current average for single room fees in your micromarket is: ' . avg_fees($competitors, $mm_avg_fees, $data_available);
```

Comment: please post a var_dump($competitors);

Comment: Try changing this `if ($competitor->minSingleCareFee != NULL) {` to this `if (!is_null($competitor->minSingleCareFee)) {`

Comment: can't help till we know whats inside $competitors. So post var_dump($competitors) as suggested by @user574632

Comment: @user574632 here's a chunk of the data dump:  array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#153 (41) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["PostcodeinCodepointFormat"]=> string(6) "XXXXX" ["Home_name"]=> string(9) "XXXXXX" ["minSingleCareFee"] string(3) "750"

Comment: @SankalpBhatt here's the data dump:
array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#153 (41) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["PostcodeinCodepointFormat"]=> string(6) "XXXXX" ["Home_name"]=> string(9) "XXXXXX" ["minSingleCareFee"] string(3) "750"

etc...

Comment: Are you sure its returning `NULL` ? Might be `boolean`. Try `if ($competitor->minSingleCareFee){ .....` or try to use `!==` instead of `!=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
//declaring variables
$mm_avg_fees = 0;
$data_available = 0;

//function to calculate average fees
function avg_fees($competitors, $mm_avg_fees, $data_available){

        foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {
            //impose condition to increment data_available
            //only if there is data in the minSingleCareFee column for the $competitor
            if (!empty($competitor->minSingleCareFee)) {
                $mm_avg_fees = $mm_avg_fees + $competitor->minSingleCareFee;
                $data_available = $data_available + 1; 
            }
        }
    return $mm_avg_fees / $data_available;
}

echo 'The current average for single room fees in your micromarket is: ' . avg_fees($competitors, $mm_avg_fees, $data_available);
```

Comment: Ok let me check... Is there a way for me to access the $data_available variable outside of the avg_fees function?

Comment: using the GLOBAL keyword. reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it inside a class? if it does, you can't do it that way.
2. The else {} is unnecessary.
3. you can do $data_available ++ instead of what's there.
4. You are treating a var as an object. What is it,  a var or an object?

   $competitor->minSingleCareFee

and you have set that competitor is the value of competitors array in that moment.

Comment: more about hints than an answer.